# Why isn't SCOPE_IDENTITY() returning my inserted ID?

Tags: sql-server, last-insert-id, scope-identity

I have an insert statement executed via `ADODB.Connection.Execute` inserting into a table on MSSQL server with an identity column, but the returned recordset does not return the ID of the newly inserted record.

I have tried the following forms of obtaining the inserted ID of the record.

```
INSERT INTO blah VALUES (blah); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
INSERT INTO blah VALUES (blah); SELECT @@IDENTITY
INSERT INTO blah OUTPUT INSERTED.ID INTO @ID VALUES(blah); SELECT ID FROM @ID
```

In all cases, when querying the recordset returned it does not contain the identity

```
var I = DB.Execute(insert_statement_from_above);
if (I) {
  var INSERTED_ID = I(0).Value;
}
```

Why might this be happening?

Comment: "auto-number column", you mean identity column?

Comment: thanks for spotting the terminology mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the table being inserted into for any INSERT triggers, and check that those INSERT triggers are using SET NOCOUNT ON.

When a trigger does not specify SET NOCOUNT ON, if it updates the database, it will generate a result set, that result set will appear before the result set that contains the SCOPE_IDENTITY result.

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189837.aspx

In reality what is happening is that the recordset contains one or more result sets.

```
TRIGGER RESULT SET
SCOPE_IDENTITY RESULT SET
```

When you query the recordset for a scope identity you are actually querying the result set output by the trigger.

You can use `RS.nextRecordset()` and then query the `SCOPE_IDENTITY` but if the trigger may or may not perform an update you end up not knowing which result set contains your `SCOPE_IDENTITY`, is it the first or the second, is there a second?

It is generally accepted good practice for triggers to specify `SET NOCOUNT ON` however if you absolutely must have `SET NOCOUNT OFF` in your trigger or have no control over the trigger, you can work around it with the following code.

Note: The Scope Identity in the examples above will always be the last result set in the recordset.  So we can find it as follows:

```
var I = DB.Execute(insert_statement_from_above);
if (I) {
  // find the result set with the scope identity in it
  while (I.State == 0) {
    I = I.nextRecordset();
  }
  var INSERTED_ID = I(0).Value;
}
```

This looks for the result set that contains your scope identity by ignoring the earlier closed result sets.

See Also:

[State property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/state-property-ado), [nextRecordset()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/nextrecordset-method-ado)

Answer (score 1):

If it's fine for you to prevent all triggers from returning the result sets, server option "Disallow returning results from triggers" might be a solution for you.

```
sp_configure 'disallow results from triggers', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
```